# DataTables warning: table id=categoryDatatable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: ajax, database, web, plugins

## [image]

the project is in Laravel. I am getting this error on different pages "DataTables warning: table id=categoryDatatable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/7"](http://datatables.net/tn/7%22)

You can visit storiesofcrime.in and login with these details

Admin login Details
email: admin@demo.com
password: 123456

Teacher login Details
email: teacher@demo.com
password: 123456

Student Login Details
email: student@demo.com
password: 123456

and please give me solution to this problem?

## [image]

the project is in Laravel. I am getting this error on different pages "DataTables warning: table id=categoryDatatable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/7"](http://datatables.net/tn/7%22)

You can visit storiesofcrime.in and login with these details

Admin login Details
email: admin@demo.com
password: 123456

Teacher login Details
email: teacher@demo.com
password: 123456

Student Login Details
email: student@demo.com
password: 123456

and please give me solution to this problem?